# Is Socket.Send buffer size limited?

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-2.0

Is there any limit for send buffer size, I can send small packs -i.e: 1000 bytes-
however when I try to send about 20K nothing happens, remote won't receive the packet
plus remote will NOT receive any more data.

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send((byte)buffer);
```

Comment: "Packet" is a UDP term.  UDP is limited to the minimum MTU: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs state, [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w93yy28a.aspx) returns the number of bytes sent.  It is your responsibility to then send the leftover bytes.

Comment: Buffer was 1024: 

`socket.BeginReceive(sm.m_StreamManager.m_Buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE_1024, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(this.ReadCallback), sm);`

Answer (score 4):

Send() returns an Int32 indicating how many bytes were sent.. so one can infer that the upper limit on your buffer size is Int32.MaxValue.

As far as why you are having trouble with a 20k byte buffer - you have not provided enough information to make a guess.

Answer (score 2):

The Socket.SendBuffer default buffer size is 8192 according to MSDN. You can increase this if needed.

```
tcpSocket.SendBufferSize = 8192;
```